# is it possible to print txt file using vim but change the font in which the text will be printed

Tags: printing, fonts, vim

my question is fully described in the title "is it possible to print txt file using vim but change the font in which the text will be printed". I found the [documentation](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/print.html) for vim where it says that this is possible, but it's not clear how to set everything up correctly

Comment: First result on searching for `font` in the page you linked to: "Printer output is controlled by the
['printfont'](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printfont') and
['printoptions'](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printoptions')
[options](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#options)." and at [`'printfont'`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printfont'): "The name of the font that will be used for |:hardcopy|."

Comment: can you please write a specific use case for example with a font "libration herif" size 14

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Read `man a2ps`, and explore all the `a2ps --list=` topics.

`a2ps` will let you specify the font, font size, as it converts ASCII to Postscript. It can even queue the print request for you, or write it's output to a file.

Invoke with:

```
:w !a2ps ...
```

Comment: can you please give a direct example, for example, set the font FreeSans 12 size

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is not suitable, I just made a post of a creak file and there were some errors, I use unicode in this file, so most likely the problem is in it

Comment: but as far as I know there is a gtk tool that allows you to print files as I need but I would like to do it through the terminal and not call PrintUnixDialog